# Overwriting rules in Sass

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I am trying to apply some custom styling to a project that uses Bootstrap (we use the Sass package which we compile ourselves). In order to be able to upgrade Bootstrap source files without merge hell I'd rather not touch any files other than _variables.scss and _bootstrap.scss (in the latter we have some custom imports).

In the Bootstrap source we have _nav.scss which contains:

```
.navbar-brand {
  ...
  padding: $navbar-padding-vertical $navbar-padding-horizontal;
  ...
}
```

My designer wants to change the styling of .navbar-brand only (and keep other .navbars as is) so I can't simply change those variables. I could add an extra class in our custom sass code + markup but that would mean overwrites on browser level.

In Sass, is there a way to overwrite rules which:

- Does not involve editing Bootstrap source files?
- Does not involve overwriting happening in compiled css in the browser?

Comment: In regards to your last bullet point, why are you trying to avoid cascading style rules?

Comment: Your solution is: ZURB Foundation :-)

Comment: Primarily for debugging issues as we still have lots of legacy code that sometimes interferes with Bootstrap. I personally use Chrome which can utilise the maps to point to uncompiled sass, other people in my team use less powerful tools. I try to keep the amount of overwriting to a minimum. Another factor is bloat, our uncompressed css is already at about 180k.

Comment: I do not see how the question this is marked to be a dupe of answers mine (except for maybe a passive aggressive "can't be done").